# Semantic error in C++ <random> Symbol XXX could not be resolved

Tags: c++, eclipse, compiler-construction, semantics

Thanks for you help. How do I remove the semantic errors?

> Symbol XXX could not be resolved

I do not want live with those red squiggly lines and error messages.

Please tell me if I MUST live with them.  I want to have the correct expectation of Eclipse or my installation.

Tools: eclipse ,windows 7, mingw 64

I get 4 semantic errors

The code does compile and execute
the lines with the comments .... red underlines have the semantic errors

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
//#include <tr1/random>
using namespace std;


int main() {
int versionid();
versionid();
int random_sort();
random_sort();
}

 int random_sort()
{
vector<int> x{888,999};
random_device rd;//red underline
std::mt19937 eng(rd());//red underline
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> u2(1,99);//red underline
         ..............elided
```

Comment: You can switch off semantic analysis. But it may show (real) errors though the code compiles.

Comment: Does it somehow tell *what* the semantic error might be? In that case, please tell us the exact error message. If not, turn them off - errors without any message what the error is are pretty useless, if the code compiles anyways.

Comment: @ArneMertz .... Symbol XXX could not be resolved.   I included this with the question.  It is my pleasure to repeat it for clarity.  If the semantic errors might be useful in the future unknown cases, I would like to know.

Comment: I really feel the need to point out that a random sort is never the best way to do a shuffle... You should be using the [Fischer-Yates](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/the-danger-of-naivete.html) shuffle instead.

Comment: @AlexReinking .... Thank You ...... in case what you wrote was serious ..... please excuse the name of function and more so lack of comments in this elided software sample.  I might be more clear to have a comment ............ //generate random numbers then sort them using std::sort or some other accepted sort.  This was a focused question and we may be out of scope of this mysterious notion of .....  Unknown Evil to me .... Demonic Horrific  Random Sort.